# asp:button not styling with css

Tags: asp.net, css, html

asp:Button will not be styled with css.

CSS:

```
.TabButton
{
    border: none;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML5:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Events" CssClass ="TabButton" OnClick ="NavigationTab_OnClick" style="background-image:url(image link)"/>
```

This doesn't work. The css code has no effect on the button. I have tried changing the "CssClass" property to just "class". Still nothing. I have also tried "id". I can style other elements using the same .css file.

Comment: have you checked in firebug weather the rule is applied to the button or not?

Comment: It takes effect in the "design" view of visual studio 2012, but not when I run the project in chrome...

Comment: do you have problem with other browsers or just chrome ?just for test change your css class to something like width:200px; to see whether it take affect or not.

Comment: Hmmm. Okay, it works in IE, but not chrome.

Comment: Cleared the browsing cache and now it works. VS2012 for web is pretty buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define inline style for image like that:

```
style="background-image:url('image link')"
```

and maybe you are missing something, that's why that class you applied not working well. Maybe some minor detail mis-matching. Otherwise it's correct.